# Integration testing on a live/running website

Tags: testing, integration

I remember reading about a framework, but have totally forgot about it and can't find it in Google.

The framework allowed you to write integration tests that are meant to be run in a live website/enviroment. It could test 3rd party connectivity/firewalls, etc. It had a nice UI to see/run all the tests.

Does anyone know the framework I am looking for? What kind of integration testing is this?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't thinking of selenium? Integration testing frameworks aren't famous for UI!